# Access the Resolve Value of a Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, promise

I have a promise that resolves a variable `this.data` in a `Read Excel Service` as shown below,

```js
  parseExcel(excelFile): Promise<any>
  {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(excelFile.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onload = (e: any) => 
        {
          /* read workbook */
          const bstr: string = e.target.result;
          const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

          /* grab first sheet */
          const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
          const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

          /* save data */
          this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
          console.log("BOM PARSE SERVICE LOG: " , this.data)
          resolve(this.data);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    })
}
```

I am now trying to access the resolved array here

```js
async ReadExcel(event)
  {
    return new Promise<Object>((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      var excelContents = this.parser.parseExcel(event).then(function(value)
      {
        return value
      }
      console.log("New Quote Component Log: ", excelContents)
      //need var excelContents to only contain the array and not contain the value of the promise object
    }
  )}
}
```

the log statement in the latter function brings me back this...

[image: log statement]

Is there a way that I can have the variable `excelContents` only take on the value of the array rather than the entire value of the promise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the ReadExcel function is that .then() always returns the Promise instance, not the actual resolve value. 
So by doing `let blabla = promise.then(v => {return v})`, `blabla` variable will be the promise and to access the resolve value you'll have to do `blabla.then(v => ...)`.

That's why when you `console.log` the `excelContents` variable, you see an object with two properties, state, representing the state of the promise, and value, wich is the resolve value.

I recommend, if you are using an async function as I see you do, to use async/await like this:

```
async ReadExcel(event)
  {
    return new Promise<Object>(async(resolve, reject) =>
    {
      try {
          var excelContents = await this.parser.parseExcel(event)
          console.log("New Quote Component Log: ", excelContents)
          //need var excelContents to only contain the array and not contain the value of the promise object
          resolve(excelContents)
      } catch(e) {
         reject(e)
      }
    }
  )}
}
```

as `await promiseReturningFunc()` will return the resolve value.

Be careful of error handling, always use try/catch.

Also please notice that I added async to the promise handler.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you will need to so something asynchronous to get the real, promised data. There is obviously no hope in getting it synchronously.

Your attempt with yet another `new` promise is not helping you to get any closer (in fact, it employs [the promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)). Just do:

```
async ReadExcel(event) {
    var excelContents = await this.parser.parseExcel(event);
    console.log("New Quote Component Log: ", excelContents);
}
```

To be clear: don't be tricked into thinking that *returning* `excelContents` in this latter function is going to give you synchronous access to it. That would not bring you any benefit, because you will need to `await` that returned value again, in yet another `async` function. So... this is it. Do everything you need to do with `excelContents`, right there, in that `async` function, after `await`.